# Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression in MSAccess

Tags: database, ms-access

I have written a query in MS Access when i am trying to run this query i am getting an error. I can't find out the problem in it.

```
SELECT 
p.[ID] as [ID],
 p.[Code] as [CODE],
p.[DESCRIPTION] as [DESCRIPTION],
p.[Coloring] as [Coloring],
 p.[Sizing] as [Sizing],
p.[BarCode] as [Barcode],
p.[PartsNo] as [PartsNo],
p.[HSN_SAC] as [HSN_SAC],
p.[GSTRate] as [GSTRate],
p.[Remarks] as Remarks,
c.[CODE] as [CategoryCode],
c.[Description] as [CategoryDescription],
b.[CODE] as [BrandCode],
b.[Description] as [BrandDescription],
s.[Id] as [SupplierId],
s.[Code] as [SupplierCode],
s.[Description] as [SupplierDescription] 
FROM [PRODUCTMASTER] p LEFT JOIN [CATEGORYMASTER] c on p.[CategoryId] = c.[ID] 
LEFT JOIN [BRANDMASTER ] b on p.[BrandId] =  b.[ID] 
LEFT JOIN [SUPPLIERAMSTER] s on p.[SupplierId] =  s.[ID]
```

[image]

Comment: It might be the space after BRANDMASTER or the misspelling of SUPPLIERAMSTER.

Comment: i did check again, till now no spelling mistake found @AndyG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you linking more than two tables, brackets required:

```
FROM (([PRODUCTMASTER] p LEFT JOIN [CATEGORYMASTER] c on p.[CategoryId] = c.[ID]) 
LEFT JOIN [BRANDMASTER ] b on p.[BrandId] =  b.[ID]) 
LEFT JOIN [SUPPLIERAMSTER] s on p.[SupplierId] =  s.[ID]
```

I would recommend to build SQL queries using query builer, it's much easier than manually and you won't have misspelling and bracketing errors like this. Check one more time for the space after `[BRANDMASTER ]`, this is bad practice in any case. Remove trailing space from column name in table definition, it may cause other weird errors.

Comment: space removed but still getting the error. i don't understand why.